# How to connect to a WMS with GeoTools

Tags: java, geotools

I'm trying to learn about WMS and are using GeoTools.
And I'm getting a timeout error when executing:

```java
wms = new WebMapServer(wmsURL):

wmsURL = new URL("https://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service?");
try {
    wms = new WebMapServer(wmsURL);
} catch (IOException e) {
    //There was an error communicating with the server
    //For example, the server is down
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ServiceException e) {
    //The server returned a ServiceException (unusual in this case)
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Unable to parse the response from the server
    //For example, the capabilities it returned was not valid
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can some one tell me what is wrong? I can see the map when entering the url in QGis.

error code:

```
ALLVARLIG: Failed to execute request https://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:305)
at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:507)
at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:602)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:373)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:207)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
at org.geotools.http.SimpleHttpClient.get(SimpleHttpClient.java:134)
at org.geotools.http.SimpleHttpClient.get(SimpleHttpClient.java:105)
at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.internalIssueRequest(AbstractOpenWebService.java:455)
at org.geotools.ows.wms.WebMapServer.issueRequest(WebMapServer.java:450)
at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.negotiateVersion(AbstractOpenWebService.java:287)
at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.<init>(AbstractOpenWebService.java:124)
at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.<init>(AbstractOpenWebService.java:97)
at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.<init>(AbstractOpenWebService.java:88)
at org.geotools.data.ows.AbstractOpenWebService.<init>(AbstractOpenWebService.java:77)
at org.geotools.ows.wms.WebMapServer.<init>(WebMapServer.java:376)
at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.MapView.addargs(MapView.java:2679)
```

Tried to use curl, but I'm not sure if I'm using it correct...
[image]

Comment: do you use a proxy or firewall? does that link work from your command line with curl?

Comment: I tried Curl, se above. I also tried to turn off the Proxy = same result. I don't know about the firewall, its a big consern, with a separate security department :-(. But is there a known URL I could try with, that is correct and that I should be able to connect to with "wmsURL = new URL("....");

Comment: OK, so that shows that it is a problem with connections leaving your machine not GeoTools. That URL works fine for me both in the browser and with `curl`

Comment: Ok, I can connect to the Osm URL via QGis. What are they doing that I don't do with GeoTools?

Comment: using your proxy, negotiating with firewall - I can't tell from here